# Ruby: what is the best way to find out method type in method_missing?

Tags: ruby, method-missing, method-names

At the moment I've got this code:

```
name, type = meth.to_s.match(/^(.+?)([=?]?)$/)[1..-1]
```

But it doesn't seem to be the best solution =\

Any ideas how to make it better?
Thanks.

Comment: xyz= - setter, xyz? - checker, xyz - getter

Comment: Can you be a little bit more precise in your specification: what's the "type" of the `==` method or the `===` method? What's the "type" of a method like `Kernel#puts`?

Comment: Are you familiar with `attr_reader` and similar methods which mean you don't have to write setters or getters unless they have complicated logic?

Comment: i'm aware about class macroses and attr_* family, but this code resides in method_missing, so it has nothing to do with attr_*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option seems to be this:
`name, type = meth.to_s.split(/([?=])/)`

Comment: method "types" don't really exist, you're the only person in the whole history of the ruby universe to talk about them ;)

Comment: i know, i just don't know how to describe it, so i thought "method types" will be better than "method suffix"

Comment: Don't listen to that guy, he's an idiot. You're on the ball, they're typically referred to as "Setters" and "Getters".

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly how I'd implement my `method_missing`:

```
def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
  name = sym.to_s
  if name =~ /^(.*)=$/
    # Setter method with name $1.
  elsif name =~ /^(.*)\?$/
    # Predicate method with name $1.
  elsif name =~ /^(.*)!$/
    # Dangerous method with name $1.
  else
    # Getter or regular method with name $1.
  end
end
```

Or this version, which only evaluates one regular expression:

```
def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
  name = sym.to_s
  if name =~ /^(.*)([=?!])$/
    # Special method with name $1 and suffix $2.
  else
    # Getter or regular method with name.
  end
end
```